# xslt- XSLT 1.0 to combine selected attributes and make the attribute muti-valued, retaining the other attributes

Tags: xml, xslt

This is my XML-

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><update-all-attributes>
    <document name="http://blah">
    <price>111 USD</price>
    <color>red</red>
    <size>comfort</size>
    <cost>00012-40</cost>
    <shipping>US::Ground:0.00</shipping>
    <cost>00012-40</cost>
   <price>1999 USD</price>
    <color>black</red>
    <size>Medium</size>
    <cost>00012-40</cost>
    <shipping>US::Ground:0.00</shipping>
    <cost>00012-40</cost>
   <price>19 USD</price>
    <color>blue</red>
    <size>Large</size>
    <shipping>US::Ground:0.00</shipping>
   <price>198 USD</price>
    <color>brown</red>
    <size>Small</size>
    </document>
    </update-all-attributes>
```

I want my final XML to look like-

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <document name="http://blah">
<price>19 USD</price>
    <color>blue</red>
    <size>Large</size>
       <cost>00012-40,00012-40,00012-40,00012-40</cost>
    <price>198 USD</price>
    <color>brown</red>
    <size>Small</size>
     <shipping>US::Ground:0.00,US::Ground:0.00,US::Ground:0.00</shipping>
      <price>111 USD</price>
    <color>red</red>
    <size>comfort</size>
 <price>1999 USD</price>
    <color>black</red>
    <size>Medium</size>
    </document>
```

This is the XSLT 1.0 I have been trying with-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:key name="gr-cost" match="cost" use="."/>
    <xsl:key name="gr-shipping" match="shipping" use="."/>

    <xsl:template match="update-all-attributes">

          <xsl:apply-templates/>

    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="document">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <cost>
                 <xsl:for-each select="cost[not(following-sibling::cost/text() = ./text())]">
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </cost>
            <shipping>
                <xsl:for-each select="shipping[not(following-sibling::shipping/text() = ./text())]">
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </shipping> 
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

And this is the output xml I am getting-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document name="http://blah">
   <cost>00012-40</cost>
   <shipping>US::Ground:0.00</shipping>
</document>
```

How can I modify my XSLT 1.0 to combine similar values and make the selected attribute muti-valued, retaining the other attributes as they are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have too much code. All you need is:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="document">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <cost>
             <xsl:for-each select="cost">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </cost>
        <shipping>
            <xsl:for-each select="shipping">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </shipping> 
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

### Edit

***In response to your edited question:***

To keep any *other* element a document might have, change:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
```

to:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="@* | *[not (self::cost or self::shipping)]"/>
```

Comment: awesome thanks. The code combines the values correctly when they are equal and as well as not equal.

Comment: @Michael- How do I make sure that the rest of the attributes which are not modified in the document are coming up? right now only "shipping" and"cost" attributes are coming and my other attributes like "price" for which is not modified are not coming up.

Comment: @Meow There is no `price` in your input or in your output. But if there are *elements* you want to copy, you can copy them along the attributes of `document` e.g. `<xsl:copy-of select="@*|price"/>`.

Comment: sorry edited my XML to include that. So I want just cost and shipping to be multi valued and the rest of the attributes untouched and single as they are.

Comment: @Michael- Thanks! I did <xsl:copy-of select="@*|price"/> for the remaining 30 attributes and they are coming up as they are.

Comment: @Michael- How can I remove the duplicate vales, keeping the two attributes as multi-valued?

Comment: "*How can I remove the duplicate vales*" That would be a separate question (which I see [you already asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31738271/xslt-1-0-using-xslt-1-0-how-to-strip-the-duplicate-attributes)). And the answer can be found here: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html

Comment: Thanks! I will go over the muenchian grouping.