# xslt 1.0- Using xslt 1.0 how can I make the xslt work for multiple document elements

Tags: xml, xslt

This is my XML-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <update-all-attributes>
          <document name="http://blah">
            <price>111 USD</price>
            <color>red</color>
            <size>comfort</size>
            <cost>00012-40</cost>
            <shipping>US::Ground:0.00</shipping>
            <cost>00012-40</cost>
            <price>111 USD</price>
            <color>red</color>
            <size>comfort</size>
            <cost>00012-40</cost>
            <shipping>US::Ground:0.00</shipping>
            <cost>00012-40</cost>
            <price>111 USD</price>
            <color>red</color>
            <size>comfort</size>
            <shipping>US::Ground:0.00</shipping>
            <price>111 USD</price>
            <color>red</color>
            <size>comfort</size>
          </document>


<document name="http://blahblah">
    <price>110 USD</price>
    <color>blue</color>
    <size>super</size>
    <cost>00012-41</cost>
    <shipping>US::Ground:0.01</shipping>
    <cost>00012-41</cost>
    <price>110 USD</price>
    <color>blue</color>
    <size>super</size>
    <shipping>US::Ground:0.01</shipping>
    <cost>00012-41</cost>
    <price>110 USD</price>
    <color>blue</color>
    <size>super</size>
    <shipping>US::Ground:0.01</shipping>
    <price>110 USD</price>
    <color>blue</color>
    <size>super</size>
  </document>
</update-all-attributes>
```

I want my final XML as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
                <document name="http://blah">
                  <price>111 USD</price>
                  <color>red</color>
                  <size>comfort</size>
                  <cost>00012-40,00012-40,00012-40,00012-40</cost>
                  <shipping>US::Ground:0.00,US::Ground:0.00,US::Ground:0.00</shipping>
                </document>
            <document name="http://blahblah">
                  <price>110 USD</price>
                  <color>blue</color>
                  <size>super</size>
                  <cost>00012-41,00012-41,00012-41,00012-41</cost>
                  <shipping>US::Ground:0.01,US::Ground:0.01,US::Ground:0.01</shipping>
                </document>
```

This is the XSLT used (thanks to Thomas W)-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:key name="element-by-name" match="document/*" use="local-name()"/>


  <!-- Copy everything, unless other templates say otherwise -->
  <xsl:template match="*|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>


  <!-- Skip elements if there are elements of the same name earlier in the document. 
       Priority is set to 1 so that this template overrides other templates
       and we don't accidentally still get duplicates. -->
  <xsl:template match="*[count(. | key('element-by-name', local-name())[1]) > 1]" priority="1"/>


  <!-- This template is for elements we want to be multi-value -->
  <xsl:template match="shipping | cost">
    <xsl:copy>
      <!-- We step through all elements of the same name -->
      <xsl:for-each select="key('element-by-name', local-name())">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:if test="position() != last()">,</xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is working fine for just one document element, I have multiple document element so how can this work for all the document elements?

Comment: The output that you ask for shows duplicate values inside cost/shipping. If that's what you really want, then there's no need to do any grouping. You just need to collect them, as shown in [the answer to the first question of this series](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31733504/3016153).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by changing the key so that it uses both the name of the element and the unique id of its `document` parent for the lookup value.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:key name="element-by-name-and-parent" match="document/*" 
           use="concat(local-name(), generate-id(..))"/>

  <!-- Copy everything, unless other templates say otherwise -->
  <xsl:template match="*|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Skip siblings of the same name within the same parent element; only use first occurrence -->
  <xsl:template match="*[count(. | key('element-by-name-and-parent', 
               concat(local-name(), generate-id(..)))[1]) > 1]"
        priority="1"/>

  <!-- This template is for elements we want to be multi-value -->
  <xsl:template match="shipping | cost">
    <xsl:copy>
      <!-- Step through all elements of the same name that belong to the same parent -->
      <xsl:for-each select="key('element-by-name-and-parent', 
                concat(local-name(), generate-id(..)))">
       <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:if test="position() != last()">,</xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output (the root element is the same as in the input XML; the output that you asked for in the question has no root element):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<update-all-attributes>
   <document name="http://blah">
      <price>111 USD</price>
      <color>red</color>
      <size>comfort</size>
      <cost>00012-40,00012-40,00012-40,00012-40</cost>
      <shipping>US::Ground:0.00,US::Ground:0.00,US::Ground:0.00</shipping>
   </document>
   <document name="http://blahblah">
      <price>110 USD</price>
      <color>blue</color>
      <size>super</size>
      <cost>00012-41,00012-41,00012-41</cost>
      <shipping>US::Ground:0.01,US::Ground:0.01,US::Ground:0.01</shipping>
   </document>
</update-all-attributes>
```